# How do I prevent spaces when using Python?

Tags: python, formatting, spaces

How would I remove the spaces after the R in the following line?

```
>>>print "4/3 =", 4 / 3, "R", 4 % 3
```

I want the result to look exactly like this:

4/3 = 1 R1

I appreciate any time anyone takes to answer this question.

Comment: Read about string formatting.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> a=4
>>> b=3
>>> print "{}/{} = {} R{}".format(a, b, a//b, a%b)
4/3 = 1 R1
```

If you are using an older version of Python which doesn't support `str.format` then you can use the `%` operator:

```
>>> print "%d/%d = %d R%d"%(a, b, a//b, a%b)
4/3 = 1 R1
```

Note also that since Python 2.2 you *should* use `//` for integer division, and from Python 3 onwards, you **must** use `//`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use formatting.

```
print "4/3 = %d R%d" % (4 / 3, 4 % 3)
```

or even better, with `string.format`:

```
print "4/3 = {} R{}".format(4 / 3, 4 % 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use string format

```
print "4/3 =%d R%d" % (4 / 3, 4 % 3)
```